# How to sum and combine observations with different common variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I´m trying to combine and sum certain observations of a dataset with different values for their common variables, in this case, I am trying to combine the deaths of three age intervals (85-90), (91-95), (95+) in one only (85+) age interval. Our teacher told us it is better if we do not create a new variable and use proc means, tabulate etc.

I have read every google page and all I can find is a proc means combining and summing by variable, but I don´t need the whole group summed, just some observations of the group.

Having the dataset like:

```
   .
   .
   .
71 to 75    3
76 to 80    4
81 to 85    2
86 to 90    3
91 to 95    1
95+         3
```

I would like to have it like

```
   .
   .
   .
71 to 75    3
76 to 80    4
81 to 85    2
85+         7
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your age variable in *dataset like* a numeric with a custom format, or are values of the age variable literally `"71 to 75"`, etc..

Comment: Do your already have one observation with age='95+' and death=3?  Or do you have three observations that each have death=1 and your example is the result of doing something to it? Show us your code.

Comment: Those are literal characters variables and nope, I do not have the new observations.

Comment: Minor quip: For me, `95+` implies `>= 95`, but 95 is already in the prior category, so the label should really be `96+` or `>95`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom format to map the existing literal categorizations into a new ones.

```
* A format to map literal agecat strings to broader categories;
proc format ;
  value $age_cat_want (default=20)
'86 to 90' = '86+'
'91 to 95' = '86+'
'95+' = '86+'
;
```

This only works for concatenating categories, creating a coarser aggregation.

Example:

```
* A format to get you into the pickle you are in;
proc format;
value age_cat_have
71-75 = '71 to 75'
76-80 = '76 to 80'
81-84 = '81 to 85'
86-90 = '86 to 90'
91-95 = '91 to 95'
95-high = '95+'
;

data have;
  input age @@; 
  agecat = put (age, age_cat_have.);
datalines;
71 72 73 
76 77 78 79
82 83
87 86 86
94
99 101 113
;

proc freq data=have;
  title "Original categories are character literals";
  table agecat;
run;

* A format to map literal agecat strings to broader categories;
proc format ;
  value $age_cat_want (default=20)
'86 to 90' = '86+'
'91 to 95' = '86+'
'95+' = '86+'
;


proc freq data=have;
  title "New age categories via custom format $age_cat_want";
  table agecat;
  format agecat $age_cat_want.;
run;
```

Note: An existing literal categorization cannot be explicitly split.  You would have to make presumptions about the age value distribution within each category and impute a specific age that could be applied to a different age mapping format.